# Run-time bit copy (bit-masking) in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, bitmask

I have a problem at hand and solved it one way but I am not happy how I solved it as it doesn't work in every context. The solution has to be in C++(11).

I have a char array and an int. Given an bit-offset relative to data and a length (in bits). I want to extract the bits from offset to offset+length from the array and store them in out.

```
char8_t data[8];
int32_t out;
int32_t offset;
int32_t length;
```

[Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XY284.png) with `offset=24; length=4;`

Both the offset and the length are only available at run-time. Hence, I would like to avoid creating bitmasks. I personally solved it by casting the complete array to int64_t and then right-shift by (64-offset-length) and left-shift by (64-length).

```
out = (*(int64_t*)data) >> (64-offset-length) << (64-length);
```

**The issue:** If my array would be longer, there would be no primitive to capture the complete array. My solution wouldn't work anymore. Is there a better (scaling) way to do this?

In an ideal world I could create a pointer with a bit offset, but this is C++ not an ideal world.

**Alternatives** I thought about: Adding up bits with += on "out" by iterating through the array and left-shifting. *Quite unelegant!*

I am aware that there are similar questions out there, but either they have been poorly answered or the answers have hefty performance implications.

Comment: There is no need to cast array from the beginning. Add some initial offset. `reinterpret_cast<uint64_t const *>(data + (offset / 8))`

Comment: Still the same problem occurs if I had a uint64_t as a target and the `offset%8 != 0`. And I would need to check if I am not creating an int that is "longer than the array".

Comment: There is no problem. In this case you need to fetch `uint64_t` plus one byte.

Comment: @VTT You get unaligned access, that's a huge problem.

Comment: @PasserBy If unaligned access is a problem then offset could be adjusted to be properly aligned. The main idea is that there is no need to store entire `data` block in a single integer variable, fetching just two ints covering desired range should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your approach will depend on endianess, i.e. on whether the system stores the most significant bytes at the begin or at the end of the respective 8-byte memory block.

Second, I'd use unsigned data types, e.g. `uchar8_t data[8]` and  `uint32_t` in order to correctly deal with bit shifts and (automatic) type promotions.

If you exactly know where in your `data[8]` a specific information is stored and in which order, you could write it as follows:

```
uint32_t out = data[0] + 256*data[1]; 
...
```

Thereby, your "decoder" will be tightened to the order / meaning of the original data; your `data` may get longer than the largest integral data type; and you avoid undefined behaviour that might be introduced by shifting signed integral values over signed bits.

If your offset is not a multiple of 8, i.e. the "value" does not start at the beginning of a byte, you can still use bit shift operations to correct this. Let's assume that the value starts at an offset of 2 bits; Then you could write:

```
uint32_t out = (data[0] >> 2) + (data[1] << 6) + (data[2] << (6+8))
```

But - in the end - your target will be limited to a specific amount of bits, since the C language at your specific platform will guarantee a particular size for each of the primitive data types, `unsigned long long` probably being 64 bits still. This limit is implementation defined, the standard guarantees a minimum of bits for each data type. Whether this limit comes from registers or something else, you cannot know - its implementation defined.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Actually it was all unsigned. so uint, uchar, etc. (I forgot). The 256 is a good option to "shift" the data. If I had a uint64_t as a target and `offset%8 != 0; length=64;`, I would still have a problem though. Is this an inherent problem with the registers being a maximum of 64 bits?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `std::vector<bool>`?
It is a specialization of `std::vector` that combines the dynamic size of vector with compactness of `std::bitset`.

Comment: It's also a terrible misnomer of a container that should never have been called `vector` as it has some breaking differences from real `vector`s... and while I don't know if it will be removed from the Standard any time soon, I wonder if it might not be a great thing to recommend people start depending on.

Comment: That discussion has been around for quite a few years, and has not led to deprecation of this class AFIAK. Or has it?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use bitset as a temporary. First copy byte aligned in a loop and then perform bit alignment.

```
unsigned startbit = offset;
unsigned startbyte = startbit / 8;
unsigned endbit = offset + length - 1;
unsigned endbyte = endbit / 8;

bitset<8*(sizeof(out) + 1)> align(0);
for(unsigned byte = endbyte; byte >= startbyte; --byte) { // byte align copy
// for(unsigned byte = startbyte; byte <= endbyte; ++byte) { // check endianess
    align <<= 8;
    align |= data[byte];
}
align >>= startbit % 8; // bit align
align &= ((1 << length) - 1); // mask

out = align.to_ullong();
```

Answer (score 0):

I use `std::bitset` and `boost::dynamic_bitset` to represent binary data and manipulate them. `std::bitset` works well if the length is fixed, otherwise `boost::dynamic_bitset` is a good choice. With this, you can extract bits with overloaded bit operators:

```
#include <boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp>

using boost::dynamic_bitset;

dynamic_bitset<unsigned char> extract(unsigned char* first, unsigned char* last, int offset, int length) {
   dynamic_bitset<unsigned char> bits(first, last);

   bits >>= bits.size() - (offset  + length);
   bits.resize(length);

   return bits;
}
```

So instead of `int32_t out;` you can use `dynamic_bitset<>` to hold values of arbitrary bit length in an efficient way.